# Dell Latitude E6510 vs E6510 N series - What's the difference?

Tags: laptop

Okay guys, this is NOT a direct shopping question. I was wandering around because I need a new laptop. I've popped into this machine.

Anyway: What's the difference?
I found two models on a price list.

E6510 - N Series - Ci5 : This says "Latitude E6510 : N-Series Base"
and the other one:
Latitude E6510 - ... : This says "Latitude E6510 : Standard base"

Whats the deal? Different case? Features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The n Series is a Dell product line
>   that does not ship with a
>   pre-installed version of Microsoft
>   Windows. Apparently prohibited from
>   shipping computers without an
>   operating system by an existing
>   licensing agreement with Microsoft,
>   Dell instead ships these systems with
>   either the open-source FreeDOS
>   operating system or the Ubuntu Linux
>   distribution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_n_Series

Comment: The lack of my google-fu skills are quite disturbing.. ^^" Thanks!